# how to format output with tabulator to make table look clearlly

Tags: java, string, postgresql, formatting

I am getting an output from a postgresql. I would like to make it like nice and clear.

For example:

```
 content    | tablename | columnname | rowctid 
------------+-----------+------------+---------
 blabla     | s3        | usename    | (0,11)
 public1    | s2        | relname    | (7,29)
 public 2   | w         | body       | (0,2)
```

How can I use a tabulator and so on? I would start with this for example:

```
System.out.println(" content    | tablename | columnname | rowctid");
System.out.println("------------+-----------+------------+---------");
for (int i = 0, i<x, i++) {
System.out.println(con_var + "   |  " +tab_var + "   |  " +col_var + "   |  " +row_id);
}
```

But the tabulator doesn't work I presume. Additionally, if a word would be longer then another one, the '|' would stand at different positions.

Comment: Use `String#format(-)`..

Comment: Additionally, if a word would be longer then another one, the '|' would stand at different positions.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
    System.out.println(String.format("%30s", "content    |") 
            + String.format("%30s", "tablename |") 
            + String.format("%30s", "columnname |")
            + String.format("%30s", "rowctid |"));
    System.out.println(String.format("%30s", "+").replaceAll(" ", "-") 
            + String.format("%30s", "+").replaceAll(" ", "-")
            + String.format("%30s", "+").replaceAll(" ", "-") 
            + String.format("%30s", "+").replaceAll(" ", "-"));
    for (int i = 0, i<x, i++) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%30s", con_var + "   |  ") 
                +  String.format("%30s", tab_var + "   |  ") 
                +  String.format("%30s", col_var + "   |  ") 
                +  String.format("%30s", row_id + "   |  "));
    }
```

In this example 30 is column size. Change it as required.

Comment: but it is stil not dynamic.If i have a table where the content is 4 char long and another is 100 chars long :/ but thanks for your effort :)

Comment: @kellerprogger, You could use max column size at the place of **30**